# Performance Issue with While and Read

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a many-line file containing commas. I want to remove all of the characters appearing after a comma from the line, including the comma. I have a bash script which does this, but it isn't fast enough.

Input:

```
hello world, def
```

Output:

```
hllo worl
```

My slow script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    values="${line#*, }"
    phrase="${line%, *}"
    echo "${phrase//[$values]}"
done < "$1"
```

I want to improve the performance.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The file has several lines, maybe thousands.

Comment: Hey, there's a space after the comma. Shouldn't you remove the space between "hllo" and "worl"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Perl

```
$ perl -F',' -lane '$F[0] =~ s/[$F[1]]//g; print $F[0]' file
hlloworl
```

If you don't want to count the space after the comma:

```
$ perl -F',\s*' -lane '$F[0] =~ s/[$F[1]]//g; print $F[0]' file
hllo worl
```

Perl excels at text manipulation like this, so I'd expect this to be pretty quick.

Comment: This answer worked pretty good, the performance increased pretty well, thanks Glenn, I have not ever used Perl, I always choose bash, sed, awk solutions for my text processing, I will start to write Perl solutions, thanks!!! FYI: The answer that worked for me was your second one.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the `while` loop could give your code a boost, most programs take a file as input and will do the reading for you.

You can replace your program with the following and report the times:

```
cut -d"," -f1 < file
```

You can try with `awk`, changing the field separator to `,`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}; {print $1}' file
```

Also you could try with `sed` (with the modifications suggested by [@Qualia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905448/qualia)):

```
sed -r -i "s/,.*//g" file
```

Beware though, that the `-i` flag will inplace edit your file, if that is not the desired effect you can just do:

```
sed -r "s/,.*//g" file
```

Comment: The original question says nothing about inplace editing, so you might want to explain that to prevent accidental data destruction. Your answers don't appear to match the desired output.

Comment: The question is to remove the letters after the `,` from the letters before the `,`

Answer (score 0):

An AWK solution (edited taking inspiration from @glenn jackman's perl solution):

```
awk -F", " '{ gsub("["$2"]",""); print $1 }' "$1"
```

With this sort of line processing, it's often better to use a compiled solution. I would use Haskell for its expressiveness:

```
-- answer.hs
import Data.List(nub, delete)
import Data.Char(isSpace)
main = interact (unlines . (map perLine) . lines)
perLine = strSetDiff . break (==',')
strSetDiff (s, ',':' ':sub) = filter (`notElem` sub)) s
strSetDiff (s, _) = s
```

Compile with the command `ghc -O2 answer.hs`.

This `break`s each line into two lists `s` and `sub` on `,`, removes the `", "` from `sub`, and then filters `s` to remove characters that are elements of `sub`. If there is no comma, the result is the whole line.

This assumes a space always follows a `,`. Otherwise remove the `' ':` and replace `notElem sub` with `notElem (dropWhile isSpace sub)`

Time taken for an 80000 line file consisting of 10 lines repeated 8000 times:

```
$ time ./answer <infile >outfile
0.38s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.386 total

$ time [glenn jackman\'s perl]
0.68s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.691 total

$ time awk -F", " '{ gsub("["$2"]",""); print $1 }' infile > outfile
0.85s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 0.897 total

$  time ./ElBarajas.sh infile > outfile
2.77s user 0.32s system 99% cpu 3.105 total
```

Personally, I'm willing to admit defeat - the perl solution seems best to me.